# This shloka is from which scripture?

Tags: identification-request, shloka, reference-request

Looking for scriptural reference for this shloka.:

> आकाशस्याधिपो विष्णुरग्नेश्चैव महेश्वरी।
> वायोः सूर्यः क्षितेरीशो जीवनस्य गणाधिपः।।